# Why can't the compiler automatically infer the type returned by Iterator::collect?

Tags: rust, iterator, type-inference

This is my code:

```rust
fn tests() {
    let v1: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let v2 = v1.iter().map(|x| x + 1).collect();

    assert_eq!(v2, vec![2, 3, 4]);
}
```

I get an error:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
 --> src/lib.rs:3:9
  |
3 |     let v2 = v1.iter().map(|x| x + 1).collect();
  |         ^^ consider giving `v2` a type
```

I must give `v2` a type like this:

```rust
let v2: Vec<_> = v1.iter().map(|x| x + 1).collect();
```

Why can't the compiler automatically infer this?